# Advertising or redirecting to new website

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web, ads

The website of our institution supports 30 languages and it has almost 400,000 articles. It's Global Rank in [alexa.com](http://www.alexa.com) is always between 11000 to 11500 and we are always on the top 5 google result if any body search on what we are working. Every day we receive almost  200 emails from people all around the world.

We recently developed a new version of our website by [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org) with a slightly different URL.
The old url is like this `example.com/html/LANGUAGE/...` but the new one is `LANGUAGE.EXAMPLE.COM` so we need to somehow tell current users to visit the new website **without loosing our Global and Google rank**.

The most straightforward solution is to modify the header of our website and ask the users to visit the new one but our chief ask me to examine the redirecting method and see what the conclusions of doing this is going to be.

I would like to know If I redirect every `example.com/html/LANGUAGE/*` to `LANGUAGE.example.com` will this effect our Global Rank on [Google](http://google.com)? Won't this redirection to the front page be a negative factor in Google? like 403 redirect?  or Is there any better solution for our problem?

**Note:** There is no logical relationship between the content of old website to the new one. I mean there is no mapping between the contents so when a user visits a content in old website there is no way to redirect him to new website of the same content. He must be redirected to the front page

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First of all Alexa rank related with your traffic data but Google PageRank calculating with various factors.

Positive factors are; backlinks, high traffic, correctly written meta tags, meta tags should be related with your body content etc.

Negative factors are; broken links, unrelated keywords, unexpected page content changes etc.

On your situation;

- First you should definitely redirect all of your pages to new
  destination.
- Access to [Google Web Master Tools Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en).
- Send sitemap of your new website.
- Checkout Crawling Errors tab and correct the issues.
- You won't face a huge impact on Alexa Rank if you redirect all of your pages correctly
- Checkout Google Index > Content Keywords you should arrange your new website protecting these keyword chart.

I think Google Web Master Tools is crucial for you. As I said you can't do much things for Alexa Rank.

*I don't recommend you to empty your parent domain and using a subdomain. Subdomain is here for secondary contents.

Comment: I believe it's called Google Search Console now. But it seems to live at the same URL(s) anyway.

Comment: Checkout this search results: https://www.google.com.tr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20webmaster%20tools

Comment: I am going to redirect the users to the front page of new website not the related content. Won't google count on this as a broken link or 403 redirect?

Comment: Design a rewrite rule in your .htacces file(parent domain) and redirect all old link to new links of related pages.

Comment: @mertyildiran  There is no logical relationship between the contents of old website to the new one. I have to redirect to front page.

Comment: @Drupalist if so, yes, you should at least make redirects to front page